# Apache Chemistry Workbench support for Centos 7 Desktop

Tags: apache, opencmis, chemistry

We are trying to install Apache Chemistry Workbench 1.1.0 on Centos 7 desktop. We are facing a blocker where we are not able to get the GUI for the application.

Centos 7 environment has Java 1.8.161 installed.

Please help me in understanding the issue.

Attaching screenshot for the reference.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: The CMIS Workbench is a Java Swing application. Do other Swing applications work?

Comment: Tried to execute eclipse which works well.

Comment: Eclipse is not a Java Swing application.

Comment: Tried to install Squirrel client. Getting the same issue